# Does <This line of code> Can help adsense to supply relevant ads if there's no written content on the site?

Tags: ads, adsense, meta-tags

I have a small question, doubt:

If I have a website, where I can't place some written content, I mean, almost everything is graphical, so I was wondering is this line of code:

```
<meta name="keywords" content="_The Keywords go here_">
```

Can replace adsense's source for keywords in the content in order to supply the site with relevant ads for the users based on what the site actually do... I mean, will adsense take the keywords from that string of code?

Do anyone Know? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AdSense was really designed for use on text-based pages, but Google doesn't actually define what "content" means or anything like minimum word count, etc. Google's main criteria is whether or not the site is useful to human readers. If your site is image-heavy because that's what makes it appealing to visitors then that's OK. If it's image-heavy for less legitimate reasons (i.e. converting scraped content into images) then that will land you into trouble.

Given the site is legitimate, there are a number of things you can do to help AdSense target your pages correctly:

- **Basic SEO** — Have a relevant title, use the meta description and keywords tags (no keyword stuffing!), use one or two headings, put the primary keyword in the URL, use descriptive ALT tags for the images, etc.
- **Add some text** — Even if you're image-heavy, there must be some way to include a few lines of text somewhere on the page. Maybe at the bottom.
- **Privacy policy and contact information** — A privacy policy is required by Google. Contact information is also a good idea for legitimacy.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Good info, it helped me back in the day... The simple answer was "yes" anyway... hehe.